# Java classes from database architecture

Tags: java, android, database, retrofit

I have a relatively simple database containing a `Player` table (a single field `username`) and a `Game` (a single field `date`) one. As a `Player` can take part in multiple `Game` and a `Game` can be played by multiple `Player`, I use a `many-to-many` relationship where an extra column `score` is added to the joined table to store the score of a `Player` in a `Game`.

In my Java code, I have obviously a `Player` class with field `username` and a `Game` one with field `date`. However, I do not know if I should create a third class for the join table or if I should add a `List<Player>`attribute within the `Game` class along with a list of `List<Integer>` to store the score.

EDIT: Example

`Player` table:

```
player_id  player_name
    1         Bob
    2         Lea
    3         John
```

`Game` table:

```
game_id   game_date
1         20/08/2017
2         19/08/2017
```

`Joined` table:

```
game_id  player_id  score
1          1        50
1          2        35
2          1        50
2          3        29
```

Comment: code is main way communication betweem programmers. Not free story

Comment: How exactly do you plan to `join` a `Game` with a `Player` if there is no primary key - foreign key relationship between them? The storage structure is useless post storage.

Comment: The join table will contain 2 foreign keys (one for `Player` and one for `Game`).

Comment: Why not have two more columns in `Game` called `player name` and `score`. As I understand, each row in `Game` represents the date on which the game was played. Add the player name and score to it and you don't really need the third table IMO? The `Game` table could probably be renamed to `GameHistory`?

Comment: But I have multiple `Player` for a given `Game`

Comment: Yup. You add one row per player in the `GameHistory` table just like you would in the third table? Do post some pseudo code so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Instead of the `player name` you suggest, it could be the `player_id` as a foreign key?

Comment: Example added in the first post.

Comment: How many players are supposed to be in 1 game?

Comment: At least two players

Answer (score 1):

I would not create a separate class for the `joined` table. I would go with a `Map<Player, Integer>` in the `Game` class to hold the players in the game and their respective scores.

Something like so (simple, no error checks):

```
class Game {

    Map<Player, Integer> playerScores = new HashMap<>();

    void addPlayer(Player p) {
        playerScores.put(p, 0);
    }

    void incrementScore(Player p, int increment) {
        int newScore = getScore(p) + increment;
        playerScores.put(p, newScore);
    }

    int getScore(Player p) {
        return playerScores.get(p);
    }

    // etc...

}
```

Comment: Suppose I have a second extra attribute in the joined table, the `Map` solution cannot be implemented right?

Comment: If you have more than one attribute, you could try with a simple bean class containing all attributes and use instances of that, instead of the Integer in the example. But this might not be the best solution.

Comment: Yes, I think having a second class `PlayerInGame` with a `Player` attribute and all extra attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add score attribute to Player class?
1 player probably can't be in 2 games at same time, right?

Reason why I say this is because you would then need only one list, with your approach you end up with 2 lists which are not directly connected. Yes I know that you will place player and his score at same index but this complicates things a lot.

Situation that I can think of just now is showing scoreboard, in other to show which player has highest score you need to sort it, how would you do it with your 2 lists?

In some complicated way for sure, you would first need to connect first and second list in some structure like map or something, probably you would need to use `TreeMap<Integer, List<Players>>`, where Integer would be the score and for each score you would need List of players because 2 or more players could have same score.

By having score in your Player class you avoid this complications and make accessing score of each player very easy, once they leave game you simply take score, save in database and set back to 0.